# C# error: Cannot Convert 'string[]' to 'string'

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write some C# code for Unity that will read from a text file, store each line in a string array, and then convert it to a 2D char array.

The error occurs at:

```
void ReadFile()
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/Maze1.txt");
    int length = read.ReadLine().Length;
    maze = new string[length, length];
    line = new string[length];

    while(!read.EndOfStream)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        {
            line[i] = read.ReadLine();
        }
        for( int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        {
            for( int j = 0; j <= length; j++)
            {
                maze[i,j] = line[i].Split(','); // <---This line is the issue.
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

The Exact error I am getting is:

```
Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix the code?

Comment: this line: int length = read.ReadLine().Length; will advance the stream for one line and later in the for loop you start reading from line 2.

Comment: Yea, that is fine, the file is the same length, width and height wise.

Comment: but do you need the first line of the text or not? because in your code, the first line will be missed.

Comment: Yea, thank you I realized what you meant. that fixed the second part of the issue after I got the maze to start drawing.

Comment: ok, have a look at my answer and see whether that works for you. don't forget to accept the answer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling you meant to do this:

```
    for( int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        var parts = line[i].Split(',');
        for( int j = 0; j <= length; j++)
        {
            maze[i,j] = parts[j];
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped. I was able to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As error says `maze[i,j]` will take a `string` but `line[i].Split(',');` would return a `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The better data structure for the maze is in your case an array of arrays, instead of the 2d array. So you can assign the result of the split operation directly without the extra copy:

```
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/Maze1.txt");
string firstLine = read.ReadLine();
int length = firstLine.Length;
string[][] maze = new string[length][];

maze[0] = firstLine.Split(',');

while(!read.EndOfStream)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        maze[i] = read.ReadLine().Split(',');
    }
}
```

You can then access the maze similar to the 2d array:

```
var aMazeChar = maze[i][j];
```